# Finding $\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan(p\cdot x)\cdot \arctan(q\cdot x)}{x^2} \text{d}t$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I am attempting to derive the value of the integral
$$
I(p,q)= \int\limits_0^\infty \frac{\arctan(p\cdot x)\cdot \arctan(q\cdot x)}{x^2} \text{d}x
$$
Differentiating the I w.r.t. p and then q gives the expression
$$
\frac{\partial^2 I}{\partial p \, \partial q} = \frac{\pi}{2(p+q)}
$$

Now I want to solve this equation but unclear as to how the constant(s) of integration may be found.

Comment: $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\arctan\left(pt\right)\arctan\left(qt\right)}{t^{2}}dt=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(p\ln\left(1+\frac{q}{p}\right)+q\ln\left(1+\frac{p}{q}\right)\right)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fact that $I(p,0) = I(0,q) = 0$.

Comment: Plus the derivatives vanish when an argument is $0$.